# CSS pulsating dots with text inside them

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to add text inside a pulsating dot.

Here's my current HTML (data inside `h4` and p tags is dynamic)

```
<div class="pulsating-circle">
  <h4>two lines title</h4>
  <p>two lines of text</p>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS (scss) (https://jsfiddle.net/24cdn65x/):

```
.pulsating-circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 232px;
    height: 232px;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 150%;
        height: 150%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left: -25%;
        margin-top: -25%;
        border-radius: 150%;
        background-color: #ccc;
        animation: pulse-ring 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) infinite;
    }

    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; 
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 232px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -.4s infinite;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm not being able to properly locate the text inside the div.

I've tried wrapping the pulsating circle on a relative div and also the content inside the pulsating circle inside a relative div.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve
[image: pulsating dot with text]

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Can you add a JSfiddle or the like? Code help questions need the problem replicated in the smallest way possible so we're not shooting in the dark.

Comment: @rotateDev here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/24cdn65x/ div data is dynamic, so it can be under content

Comment: See my answer - there are a couple other good solutions here, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the text div a z-index of 1 and an absolute position:

```css
.pulsating-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 232px;
  height: 232px;
}

.pulsating-circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  border-radius: 150%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: pulse-ring 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) infinite;
}

.pulsating-circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 232px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -0.4s infinite;
}

.text{
  
   position: absolute;
    top: 68px;
    left: 90px;
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes pulse-ring {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.33);
  }
  80%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse-dot {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first-color pulsating-circle">
  <div class="text">
    <h4>test title</h4>
    <p>text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, it will break if the text in the title becomes too long. Update the title text to be longer, you'll see what happens.Take a look at my answer to see how dynamic text is accounted for. I think this answer should be updated to reflect changing/longer text situations.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is what I came up with. Looks to be completely dynamic, as long as you don't put in an insane amount of copy. Setting the parent div `pulsating-circle` to position:relative, and simply aligning it via margin will give you way more leeway when trying to center your text. After this, you can put your content in its own div and set its position to absolute, therefor using the parents height as the determining factor.

```
<div class="first-color pulsating-circle">
  <div class="first-text">
    <h4>test title that cant test title that cant</h4>
    <p>texttext text text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.pulsating-circle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 232px;
  height: 232px;
}

.first-text {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yjtqenz0/16/

Sorry for the jumbled properties!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the html you have then you can do this:

```
<div class="pulsating-circle">
  <h4>Here is a Header</h4>
  <p>two lines of text two lines of text</p>
</div>

.pulsating-circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 232px;
    height: 232px;
    border-radius: 232px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -.4s infinite;
}

.pulsating-circle h4{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pulsating-circle p{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wpybjdks/

Comment: Sorry, but the content on the div is dynamic

Comment: @Lucas Sure no worries. Take a look at the updated answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting like this:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, white 50%, #f2f2f2 50%) no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pulsating-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 232px;
  height: 232px;
}

.pulsating-circle div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: inherit;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.pulsating-circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -50%;
  margin-top: -50%;
  border-radius: 150%;
  background-color: #00BCDA;
  animation: pulse-ring 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) infinite;
}

.pulsating-circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -25%;
  top: -25%;
  display: block;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  border-radius: 232px;
  background-color: #00BCDA;
  animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -0.4s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse-ring {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.33);
  }
  80%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse-dot {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pulsating-circle">
  <div>
    <h4>Two lines title</h4>
    <p>Two lines of text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't have the animation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that allows for some dynamic text and centers the `h4` and `p` vertically/horizontally. I added a class to the inner div (`.inner`) to target it a little easier in the CSS.

A fiddle to play with:
https://jsfiddle.net/fgyovexw/

```css
.pulsating-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 232px;
  height: 232px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pulsating-circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  border-radius: 150%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: pulse-ring 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) infinite;
}

.pulsating-circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 232px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -0.4s infinite;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 140px;
}

.inner>h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.inner>p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes pulse-ring {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.33);
  }
  80%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse-dot {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first-color pulsating-circle">
  <div class="inner">
    <h4>long text here for title content</h4>
    <p>text text text text text and more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example:

```css
.pulsating-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 232px;
  height: 232px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pulsating-circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  border-radius: 150%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: pulse-ring 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) infinite;
}

.pulsating-circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 232px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation: pulse-dot 1.25s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) -0.4s infinite;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 140px;
}

.text > h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.text > p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes pulse-ring {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.33);
  }
  80%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse-dot {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first-color pulsating-circle">
  <div class="text">
    <h4>test title</h4>
    <p>text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```